# I need to assign a number to a letter

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to allocate a number to a letter in excel.
For instance, if I type a, it must equate to 33, b must be 44, c must be 51, and so on.  How do I do this?

Comment: Since there are a lot of letters, and the assigned values look arbitrary (i.e., not a "mathematical" relationship that can be translated with a simple formula), this would typically be done by creating a table of the letters and their assigned values, then using VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH to retrieve the values.  Check out those functions.  If it is still unclear, update the question with the specific issue causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the letter to enter is in A1, then put this in B1 :

```
=INDEX({33,44,51},MATCH(A1,{"a","b","c"},0))
```

done.

p/s : please share if you din't get how to generate the 'list' /edit the formula.. ( :

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the value in some cell, then click the name box (the text box on the top left corner that shows the current cell name like A1, B2, etc.) and name the value, for example `var`

Alternatively open *Formulas > Defined Names Section > Name Manager* to manage variable names and their values

See

- [Use the Name Manager in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4)
- [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

[image: Name Manager]